# I am getting null as data when trying to get my data from mongoDB database with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I am trying to get my data from mongoDB database with axios but when i console.log() my data i get null as data below is the code

```
import './ListItem.scss'
import ListImg from '../../assest/t3.jpg'
import PlayArrowIcon from '@mui/icons-material/PlayArrow';
import AddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Add'
import ThumbUpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ThumbUp';
import ThumbDownIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ThumbDown';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from '../../axios'

function ListItem({index, item}) {
const [isHovered, setisHovered] = useState(false);
const [movie, setMovie] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
 const getMovie = async () => {
   try {
     const response = await axios.get('/movies/find/' + item, 
     {
       headers: {
         token: "Bearer //my jwt token"
      },
    });

    setMovie(response.data)
    console.log('listItem data', response)
   } catch (err) {
     console.log(err)
   }
  };
  getMovie()
  }, [item])

  return (
   <div className='listItem' 
   style={{left: isHovered && index * 225 - 50 + index * 2.5}}
   onMouseEnter={() => setisHovered(true)} 
   onMouseLeave={() => setisHovered(false)}
  >
    
  <img src={ListImg} alt="list Images" />

    {isHovered && (
      <>
    
    <video src={movie.trailer} autoPlay={true} loop></video>
      <div className="itemInfo">
        <div className="icons">
          <PlayArrowIcon className='icon'/>
          <AddIcon className='icon'/>
          <ThumbUpIcon className='icon'/>
          <ThumbDownIcon className='icon'/>
        </div>
        <div className="itemInfoTop">
          <span>{movie.duration}</span>
          <span className='limit'>{movie.limit}</span>
          <span>{movie.year}</span>
        </div>
        <div className="desc">
          {movie.desc}
        </div>
        <div className="genre">{movie.genre}</div>
      </div>
    </>
    )}
   </div>
  )
}
export default ListItem
```

please what am i missing i have tried all i can.

1. My MongoDB database is populated with data
2. I want to use the data i get in my code
3. statusText : "OK"
4. status is 200

Comment: why you mentioned MongoDB? you make http request to API endpoint. Is it working? Have you tried curl or postman to test the endpoint - do they return data?

Comment: in my console i am getting null as data

Comment: maybe your backend cannot find movie by ID and return empty answer? Or you send 404 status in this case?

Comment: I think it cannot find movie by Id so i cleared the entire database and start again

Answer (score 0):

can you check "response.data" in your console log ? and also check your network tab to make sure your frontend is getting proper responses. You can use Postman or insomnia to test your endpoint and check whether the response getting or not.

```
console.log('response data:', response.data);
```

Comment: using postman i am getting null

Comment: check whether your MongoDB data is stored and ensure your endpoint (/movies/find/) is correct. watch tutorials on how to fetch data from MongoDB it will help you get actual data.